# How to set custom model object for each element when using *ngFor in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an Angular Dart page where I need to create a component on the screen for each item in a collection.  The items are custom model objects:

```
    class CohortDataSourceAssay{
      String name;
      String displayName;
      bool selected;
      List<String> platforms = new List<String>();

      CohortDataSourceAssay();
    }
```

I have a parent page where I want to create a template for each element in a collection of the class above:

```
    <data-source-assay *ngFor="let assay of dataSource.assays"></data-source-assay>
```

Here is the markup for the data-source-assay component:

```
    <div class="dataSourceAssay">
        <material-checkbox [(ngModel)]="assay.selected" (ngModelChange)="onCbxChange($event)">{{assay.displayName}}</material-checkbox>
        <material-dropdown-select class="selectStyle"
                                  [disabled]="!assay.selected"
                                  [buttonText]="platformLabel"
                                  [selection]="assaySequencingPlatforms"
                                  [options]="sequencingPlatforms"
                                  [itemRenderer]="itemRenderer">
        </material-dropdown-select>
    </div>
```

This works insofar as it loads a block for each assay element in dataSource.assays, however the assay block does not appear to get the assay model object.  It appears to be null.  How do I pass it in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare an `@Input()` on your `<data-source-assay>` component, through which you can pass the `assay` value.

```
@Component(...)
class DataSourceAssayComponent {
  // An input makes this property bindable in the template via [] 
  // notation.
  //
  // Note: I'm not actually sure what the type of `assay` is in your
  // example, so replace `Assay` with whatever the correct type is.
  @Input()
  Assay assay;
}
```

Now in your template where you create this component, you can bind the `assay` value to the input.

```
<data-source-assay
    *ngFor="let assay of dataSource.assays"
    [assay]="assay">
</data-source-assay>
```

Remember that the local values in a template are local to that template. Meaning the `assay` you were declaring in your `ngFor` isn't visible anywhere outside of that current template.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks Leon.  I am still figuring out all the nuances of A-D.